# Как подключить phpQuery к yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, phpquery

Как подключить библиотеку phpQuery к yii2 через composer?
Объясните поподробнее пожалуйста)))))
Заранее благодарю за ответ))

Answer (score 0):

phpQuery устанавливается глобально через PEAR, а не для приложения через composer.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/